# Silverlight Bing Map Maplayer to image

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, bing-maps

I have a layer in a Bing Map control in which I am dynamically adding MapPolygons. When the polygon count gets high, performance is affected. I have been thinking about taking the polygon layer and converting it into one image file, then adding the image as a scalable element to the map. This would cut down the number of UIControls on the page at any given time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

try looking at rendering you polygons as a tile layer, here is a full source example:

http://dataconnector.codeplex.com/